# Why is the console throwing "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, css, foreach

I managed to make the code work using a for loop. However, I thought it could be more efficient to use the forEach method instead. How do I tweak my code so that it does what's expected to be doing? I'm might sound very basic, but I'm still a beginner.

```js
const list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

list.forEach(myFunction())

function myFunction(element, index) {
  element[index].className = "newColor"
}
```

```css
.newColor {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <ul class="green" src="josue">
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
    <li>Wednesday</li>
    <li>Thursday</li>
    <li>Friday</li>
    <li>Saturday</li>
    <li>Sunday</li>
  </ul>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `list.forEach(myFunction())` -> `list.forEach(myFunction)`

Comment: `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(list)) {
  myFunction(value);
}

function myFunction(element) {
 return element.className = "newColor"
}
`